# Tuple type content python

Tags: python, types, tuples, instanceof

Can I somehow see the types and size of the contents of a tuple? I'd like the output something like:

`(str, list, int)` or whatever is possible (just printing them is hard as there are nested lists)

```
x = someSecretTupleFromSomewhereElse
print type(x)

<(type 'tuple')>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> data = ('ab', [1, 2, 3], 101)
>>> map(type, data)
[<type 'str'>, <type 'list'>, <type 'int'>]
```

To also display the length you can do this, for items that aren't sequences I'll just display `None`.

```
>>> import collections
>>> [(type(el), len(el) if isinstance(el, collections.Sequence) else None)
     for el in data]
[(<type 'str'>, 2), (<type 'list'>, 3), (<type 'int'>, None)]
```

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Do you mean any iterable?

Comment: by size i ment lenght, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Vixen Ok I can change my answer but what do you want displayed if the object has no length (eg. `int`)?

Comment: It will never occur, so no worries :)